# Windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 dual boot

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04

I currently have windows 8 installed on my machine and i'm planning to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside it.
My question is, if i install Ubuntu will it replace the boot entry of windows 8 (i guess so)?

If yes, is there an easy way to restore MS bootmgr **without** the windows installation disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu along side Windows, Ubuntu will be added to Windows boot manager. Futhermore, when you boot up your computer, windows boot manager will show up since you have two operating systems to select and the DEFAULT OS is disabled.

When you uninstall Ubuntu (research that), it should remove itself from Windows Boot Manager and windows will automatically select Windows 8 as the default OS.

Ubuntu will not replace bootmanager, since Windows is the main partion, ubuntu is similar to a seperate hard drive which can be easily plugged in and out.

So to your answer, you will not need to reinstall Windows if you want to restore the default boot manager.

WINDOWS BOOT MANAGER WITH UBUNTU:

[image]

Comment: Not when you install Ubuntu alongside Windows using the program, since you can recognize the Bootup Manager for issues such as unexpected shut down.

Comment: Seems like you were right. But right after i installed, booted into win8 to do something and restarted the pc, the whole HDD got corrupted. Luckily, i had backup of important files and most of my data was on the other HDD.
Might have been something wrong on my end

Comment: Only [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) does this. The normal Ubuntu installer *will* replace the Windows bootloader with GRUB2 (and add Windows to its boot menu). There are ways to fix the Windows bootloader using a Linux LiveCD, but not sure whether any of the methods can help restore Win8's graphical bootloader yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default, non-wubi installer used to have the behaviour @Karan describes, at least in older versions. It's been a *long* time since I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, so I can't say for sure about current versions