# My BIOS does not have option to enable the Intel Virtualization Technology, what can I do?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

- Laptop: Samsung NP300E5Z
- 64-bit capable: Yes
- BIOS: Phoenix Technologies  Ltd. 05QB 29/3/2012
- Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz, 2100 Mhz, 2
  Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
- OS: Windows 8 Pro (32 bit)

I wish to install Ubuntu 64-bit through VirtualBox. But can't find Intel VT in the BIOS. What should I do?

Comment: The `Intel Pentium B950` does not even support Intel VT.

Answer (score 4):

Your processor doesn't support VT [according to Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/55627/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B950-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz); so your only option is to try a different machine.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Can U guide me with a link so that I can install Ubuntu in my computer keeping Windows 8 also (dual Boot).

Comment: To set up dual boot with Windows 8 and uBuntu, take a look at: http://superuser.com/q/562321/302

Comment: @Shanky - You don't need Intel Virtualization Technology to dual boot.  The Ubuntu website has instructions on how to install Ubuntu and keep your Windows installation.